# Android Firestore - Update object in Array leads to unsupported type

Tags: android, arrays, google-cloud-firestore

I am confused about using new firestore function

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array

In a firestore document I have the array "List" with custom objects "MyObect"

```
...update("TestArray", FieldValue.arrayUnion("Test"));
```

works fine and as expected.

But when I try this:

```
MyObject object = new MyObject(Value1, Value2);    
...update("List", FieldValue.arrayUnion(object));
```

I ended up with error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid data. Unsupported type: com.my.app.MyObject
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.UserData$ParseContext.createError(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.3:293)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter.parseScalarValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.3:405)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter.parseData(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.3:254)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter.parseArrayTransformElements(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.3:419)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter.parseSentinelFieldValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.3:335)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter.parseData(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.3:237)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.UserDataConverter.parseUpdateData(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.3:171)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.update(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.3:239)
```

**EDIT**
Here is my database structure:

/UserData/UserID/Data/DataSet01/

Under this path I have a few values like:

- name
- birth
- gender
- List(array)

birth gender List(array)

```
DocumentReference document= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document("UserData").collection("UserID").document("DataSet01");
document.update("TestArray", FieldValue.arrayUnion("test"));
```

Adds the field "TestArray" and any given string, in the case above "test".

But the following code doesnt work:

```
DocumentReference document= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document("UserData").collection("UserID").document("DataSet01");
document.update("List", FieldValue.arrayUnion(myObject));
```

Comment: Please add your database structure to see your `TestArray` as well as your `List` array.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem and found out that, using a custom object doesn't work.
So I tried with `HashMap<String,Any>`

**I Kotlin**

```
val myObject = HashMap<String,Any>()
myObject["Value1"]="Some Value"
myObject["Value2"]="Some other Value"
document.update("List", FieldValue.arrayUnion(myObject))
```

**In Java**

```
HashMap<String, String> myObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
myObject.put("Value1","Some Value");
myObject.put("Value1","Some Other Value");
document.update("List", FieldValue.arrayUnion(myObject));
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: how would we then be able to get that field as an arraylist?

Comment: Genius. Worked like a charm.